Finite-time effects in Landau Zener
Consider a two level system with a Landau-Zener Hamiltonian of the form
$$\hat{H}=\begin{pmatrix}v t&\beta\\\beta&-v t\end{pmatrix}.$$
The Landau-Zener formula provides a closed form for the probability amplitude of jumping to the excited state, given by
$P={\rm e}^{-2\pi\beta^2/v}$, which is valid in the limit $t_0\rightarrow\infty$, $t_f\rightarrow+\infty$.
However, consider a different problem with the same Hamiltonian, but now the initial and final time are chosen as to satisfy $v t_0=\alpha_0$ and $v t_f=\alpha_f$, where $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_f$ are fixed. This takes us to $t_0=\frac{\alpha_0}{v}$ and $t_f=\frac{\alpha_f}{v}$. In this case, $v$ can be interpreted as the velocity of the system to undergo the transition of the diagonal terms from $\alpha_0$ to $\alpha_f$. It takes to the system $\Delta t=\frac{\alpha_f-\alpha_0}{v}$ to undergo from $\alpha_0$ to $\alpha_f$.
Now, my interpretation is that increasing values of $v$ lead to a larger violation of the adiabatic theorem, yielding higher probability of excitation. On the other hand, small values of $v$ imply that the evolution is performed more slowly, and this should lead to a decreasing probability of excitation.
However, when I plot the probability of excitation $P$ as a function of $v$ I find that there are some oscillations with a certain frequency, but I don't see where these come from, as to my understanding and according to the previous analysis, $P(v)$ should be a monotonically increasing function, as a higher velocity of the system should lead to higher probability of excitation.
My questions are therefore:

(a) Where do these oscillations in $P(v)$ come from?
(b) This oscillations imply that there are situations where $v_1>v_2$ and $P(v_1)<P(v_2)$, i.e. a higher velocity lead to a lower probability of excitation. To me, this doesn't make any sense. Is there any physical/intuitive explanation of this?


Could you show us exactly what you are plotting, how the plot is produced and what it looks like? The formula for $P$ that you have provided does not include time, so I assume you are plotting some modified version of it, or plotting some numerical result from your Hamiltonian?

The oscillating pattern of $P(v)$ may come from some interference effect, which are ubiquitous in quantum mechanics. There is nothing illogical in the oscillations that you obtained. I would only check the two things:

The amplitude of the oscillations decrease with increasing $\Delta t$ and constant $v$
The limit at $\Delta t \to \infty$ coincides with the Landau-Zener formula.

Moreover, TDSE for Landau-Zener problem can be analytically solved using the parabolic cylinder functions, so it is even possible to compare numerical simulation with analytics for finite $\Delta t$.

I see. However, is there any quantitative way to understand this? I guess some interference effect must be beneath this, and indeed I checked the consistency of the limits of my result by comparing with the actual LZ formula. However, I would like to understand in a more numerical, concrete way the origin of this effect, and why is it related to finite time. For example, I would like to understand questions like what is the minimum time for which these oscillations are suppressed and the LZ result becomes dominant.

Maybe the oscillations you see are related to Rabi oscillations. I can think of a physical picture as follows. The non-diagonal term $\beta$ causes Rabi oscillations between levels $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, and its effect is significant only in a finite time interval when $vt \sim \beta$. The two-level system undergoes several Rabi flops, and the number of flops depends on $v$ (can be estimated as $\beta^2/v$). This would explain the oscillating pattern.

Actually, this logic would predict oscillations in $v$ even for infinite time. Maybe the absence of oscillations in the Landau-Zener formula is somehow related to the special form of the Hamiltonian. I think that for a more general problem (for example, take some nonlinear dependence of diagonal terms on $t$) there will be oscillations even for $\Delta t \to \infty$.

The transition amplitude for $\left|1\right\rangle \rightarrow\left|2\right\rangle $ is given by
$$\left\langle 2\right|\hat{U}(\Delta t)\left|1\right\rangle.$$
When dealing with the asymptotic time evolution limit, $\Delta t\rightarrow\infty$, the time evolution operator involves a limiting operation, $\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow\infty}\hat{U}(\Delta t)$, so the transition amplitude becomes
$$\left\langle 2\right|\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow\infty}\hat{U}(\Delta t)\left|1\right\rangle.$$
However, the limit operation is not commutative with the dagger operation and thus breaks unitarity. That cause the results to be non-intuitive. What one has to do is to use a truly unitary evolution operator,
$$\hat{P}(\Delta t)\,=\,\sqrt{\hat{U}^{\dagger-1}(\Delta t)\,\hat{U}^{-1}(\Delta t)}\,\hat{U}(\Delta t).$$ Then, one can show that
$$\left|\left\langle 2\right|\hat{P}(\Delta t)\left|1\right\rangle \right|\leq1.$$
